# How to get Specific Error in Laravel Auth if user is not activated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i Show error to user saying `Your account is not activated yet, please verify your Account` if the activated column in users table is 0 in laravel 5.4

Here is my Login

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}

public function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'activated' => 1,
    ];
}
```

Currently if user is not activated it says, `Credentials do not match`. I founded an old question on stackoverflow that says override your postLogin function AuthController but in laravel 5.4 authcontroller do not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be overwrite the `authenticated()` method which is called after the user logs in and then check there if it is activated:

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( !$user->activated ) {
        auth()->logout();

        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Your account is not activated yet, please verify your Account.']);
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Also note that you have to add a similar  `$user->activated` check in your **auth** middleware, because otherwise users would be able to login trough forgotten password page.

Comment: Why are we telling user after being authorized in application that your account is not active? isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @AniketSingh, like I said that is the easiest way. You could also overwrite the `validateLogin()` method and run a query there with the credentials to see if the user has been activated.